# Save Data to Firebase Realtime Database in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In my code the user is Sign in through phone authentication.After login i want to get the user id of the user and add it to the Firebase database along with its personal details.

But when i have done this the Path in database is direct rather than it should be via first UserId then under that the personal details.
I have also provide the image with the database output.

Code:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:udharibook/Screens/SignInPage.dart';
import 'package:udharibook/Screens/dashboard.dart';

class AuthService  {
  String UserId ='';
  final DBRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('Users');
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  handleAuth(){
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (BuildContext, snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          getCurrentUser();
          writeData();
          return DashboardPage();
        }
        else {
          return SignIn();
        }
      },
    );
  }
  getCurrentUser() async{
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    final uid = user.uid;
    // Similarly we can get email as well
    //final uemail = user.email;
    UserId = uid;
    print('User ID:  '+UserId);

    //print(uemail);
  }

  void writeData(){
    DBRef.child(UserId).set({
      'id':'ID1',
      'Name':'Mehul Jain',
      'Phone':'8856061841'
    });
  }

  signOut(){
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }

  signIn(AuthCredential authCreds){
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(authCreds);
  }

  signInWithOTP(smsCode,verId){
    AuthCredential authCreds = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: verId,
        smsCode: smsCode
    );
    signIn(authCreds);
  }
}
```

Database Image [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
  void writeData() async{
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    final uid = user.uid;
    DBRef.child(uid).set({
      'id':'ID1',
      'Name':'Mehul Jain',
      'Phone':'8856061841'
    });
  }
```

Remove the `getCurrentUser()` method and retrieve the `uid` in `writeData()`

Answer (score 3):

`getCurrentUser()` method is an async method, so it not sure that your userId will be having value before the `writeData()` method is called.

so what you can do is call `writeData()` after completion of `getCurrentUser()` method i.e. :

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:udharibook/Screens/SignInPage.dart';
import 'package:udharibook/Screens/dashboard.dart';

class AuthService  {
  String UserId ='';
  final DBRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('Users');
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  handleAuth(){
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (BuildContext, snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          getCurrentUser();
          //call writeData() from inside the above method
          return DashboardPage();
        }
        else {
          return SignIn();
        }
      },
    );
  }
  getCurrentUser() async{
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    final uid = user.uid;
    // Similarly we can get email as well
    //final uemail = user.email;
    UserId = uid;
    print('User ID:  '+UserId);
    //print(uemail);
    
    //Here you add the method calling 
    writeData();
  }

  void writeData(){
    DBRef.child(UserId).set({
      'id':'ID1',
      'Name':'Mehul Jain',
      'Phone':'8856061841'
    });
  }

  signOut(){
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }

  signIn(AuthCredential authCreds){
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(authCreds);
  }

  signInWithOTP(smsCode,verId){
    AuthCredential authCreds = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: verId,
        smsCode: smsCode
    );
    signIn(authCreds);
  }
}
```